# Is my PageRank/linkjuice affected after 301 redirect and losing social likes?

Tags: 301-redirect, facebook, pagerank, like, google-plus-one

I had to restructure my URL's and had to introduce some 301 redirects. However, then the Facebook likes and Google +1's of the old pages are also lost.

Besides it's a shame those numbers don't show anymore, is my PageRank/linkjuice affected by the loss in likes/+1's?

P.S.: I know a 301 redirect by itself results in a slight linkjuice loss, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: +1's, likes, shares and tweets do not improve PageRank as we know off, however Google has suggested that they use social mentions in actual rankings to some what degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google pushes most if not all of the Pagerank to the new page when you use a "301 Moved Permanently" redirect.

Google has been ambiguous on the "all or most" point in the past.   Here is the latest video that Matt Cutts posted answering: [What percentage of Pagerank is lost through a 301 redirect?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Filv4pP-1nw).   After that, lots of people were still confused in the [forum discussion on WebmasterWorld about that video](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4548792.htm).

The loss of likes and tweets shouldn't effect your Pagerank.  Pagerank is a measure of inbound links not of social signals.

Answer (score 0):

There's no effect on page rank if redirection is used. If the URL is rewritten then you may lose your page rank and back links.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation about why you think this is the case? Some references would be really helpful.